# examination paper keeps answer's space white

Tags: tcolorbox

I make an examination paper template, the paper contains the questions and answers, a switcher is defined for showing on/off answers. it gives all when switcher is on, otherwise only the questions with the leaving answer's space for writing answers.

the package [tcolorbox](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox) is used to style the answer place. the package **hyperref** also is used to reference the question's number somtimes.

But something maybe go wrong, the answers cannot be "white"(hidden), and autoref with link also cannot be hidden when using amsmath theorem style instead of tcolorbox.

the MWE is below.

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \def\exampleboxedtext{
         convenient way to generate a new theorem type. On the other hand, it enforces to use a titled
        \begin{equation}x^2 +y^2 =1\end{equation}
        a convenient way to generate a new theorem type. On the other hand, it
    }

    \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
    %------------------------
    \newcommand{\drtitt}{ %
        \node[anchor=north east,
        inner xsep=0pt,xshift=0.8em, %yshift=-0.2em,
        font=\bfseries] at (frame.north west) (tit) {\strut \fbox{ans}};
    }
    \newcommand{\drawTCBtopl}{
        \draw[line width=1.5pt,blue]([xshift=-2em,yshift=-0.2em]frame.north west)--([yshift=-0.2em]frame.north east); %top line
        }
    \newcommand{\drawTCBbotl}{
        \draw[line width=1.5pt,blue]([xshift=1.5em,yshift=0.3em]frame.south west)--([yshift=0.3em]frame.south east);
    }
    \newtcolorbox{examsolv}{ %
        empty,breakable,
        beforeafter skip=0pt,
        leftright skip=0pt,
        width=\dimexpr\linewidth+28pt\relax,
        text width=\linewidth-1mm,
        enlarge left by=-12pt,
        overlay unbroken ={\drtitt;\drawTCBtopl;\drawTCBbotl},
        overlay first={\drtitt; \drawTCBtopl},
        overlay middle={},
        overlay last={\drawTCBbotl},
        frame code={},interior code={},
        top=0pt,bottom=0pt,right=0pt
    }

    \newtoggle{showans} %etoolbox
    \togglefalse{showans}

    \newcommand{\yesnoans}[1]{\iftoggle{showans}{#1}{\color{white} #1}}
    \newenvironment{ansonoff}[1][0em]{ %
        \yesnoans
        \begingroup\begin{examsolv} %
        }{\end{examsolv} %
        \endgroup%
    }

    \usepackage{hyperref}

    \begin{document}

    \section{test}\label{sc:testsc}

    Switcher "showans" is off, but only the side text is hidden, the body still is showed. 

    \begin{ansonoff}
    \exampleboxedtext 
    that the ref with link like this \autoref{sc:testsc} cannot be hidden.
    this is a new problem! the typing text also cannot be hidden.
    \end{ansonoff}

    \lipsum[66]

    \begin{examsolv}
    \lipsum[66]
    \end{examsolv}

    \lipsum[66]

    \begin{enumerate}
    \item \lipsum[66]
    \begin{ansonoff}
        \lipsum[66-70]
    \end{ansonoff}
    \item \lipsum[66]
    \end{enumerate}

    \lipsum[66]
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hide the answer part by setting the color to white, but the color setting of a `tcolorbox` has to be specified by e.g. `colupper`. Note that this does not influence the frame color of the link:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\exampleboxedtext{
     convenient way to generate a new theorem type. On the other hand, it enforces to use a titled
    \begin{equation}x^2 +y^2 =1\end{equation}
    a convenient way to generate a new theorem type. On the other hand, it
}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
%------------------------
\newcommand{\drtitt}{ %
    \node[anchor=north east,
    inner xsep=0pt,xshift=0.8em, %yshift=-0.2em,
    font=\bfseries] at (frame.north west) (tit) {\strut \fbox{ans}};
}
\newcommand{\drawTCBtopl}{
    \draw[line width=1.5pt,blue]([xshift=-2em,yshift=-0.2em]frame.north west)--([yshift=-0.2em]frame.north east); %top line
    }
\newcommand{\drawTCBbotl}{
    \draw[line width=1.5pt,blue]([xshift=1.5em,yshift=0.3em]frame.south west)--([yshift=0.3em]frame.south east);
}
\newtcolorbox{examsolv}{%
    empty,breakable,
    beforeafter skip=0pt,
    leftright skip=0pt,
    width=\dimexpr\linewidth+28pt\relax,
    text width=\linewidth-1mm,
    enlarge left by=-12pt,
    overlay unbroken ={\drtitt;\drawTCBtopl;\drawTCBbotl},
    overlay first={\drtitt; \drawTCBtopl},
    overlay middle={},
    overlay last={\drawTCBbotl},
    frame code={},interior code={},
    top=0pt,bottom=0pt,right=0pt
}

\newtoggle{showans} %etoolbox
\togglefalse{showans}

\newcommand{\yesnoans}[1]{\iftoggle{showans}{#1}{\color{white} #1}}

\newenvironment{ansonoff}{%
  \iftoggle{showans}{}{\color{white}\tcbset{colupper=white}}% <------------ Edited 
  \begin{examsolv}%
  }{\end{examsolv}%
}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{test}\label{sc:testsc}

Switcher "showans" is off, but only the side text is hidden, the body still is showed.

\begin{ansonoff}
\exampleboxedtext
that the ref with link like this \autoref{sc:testsc} cannot be hidden.
this is a new problem! the typing text also cannot be hidden.
\end{ansonoff}

\lipsum[66]

\begin{examsolv}
\lipsum[66]
\end{examsolv}

\lipsum[66]

\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[66]
\begin{ansonoff}
    \lipsum[66-70]
\end{ansonoff}
\item \lipsum[66]
\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative to setting the color to white is putting the stuff into the lower part of the `tcolorbox`. The lower part can be hidden by `lowerbox=invisible`. This removes the complete content:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\exampleboxedtext{
     convenient way to generate a new theorem type. On the other hand, it enforces to use a titled
    \begin{equation}x^2 +y^2 =1\end{equation}
    a convenient way to generate a new theorem type. On the other hand, it
}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
%------------------------
\newcommand{\drtitt}{ %
    \node[anchor=north east,
    inner xsep=0pt,xshift=0.8em, %yshift=-0.2em,
    font=\bfseries] at (frame.north west) (tit) {\strut \fbox{ans}};
}
\newcommand{\drawTCBtopl}{
    \draw[line width=1.5pt,blue]([xshift=-2em,yshift=-0.2em]frame.north west)--([yshift=-0.2em]frame.north east); %top line
    }
\newcommand{\drawTCBbotl}{
    \draw[line width=1.5pt,blue]([xshift=1.5em,yshift=0.3em]frame.south west)--([yshift=0.3em]frame.south east);
}
\newtcolorbox{examsolv}{%
    empty,breakable,
    beforeafter skip=0pt,
    leftright skip=0pt,
    width=\dimexpr\linewidth+28pt\relax,
    text width=\linewidth-1mm,
    enlarge left by=-12pt,
    overlay unbroken ={\drtitt;\drawTCBtopl;\drawTCBbotl},
    overlay first={\drtitt; \drawTCBtopl},
    overlay middle={},
    overlay last={\drawTCBbotl},
    frame code={},interior code={},
    top=0pt,bottom=0pt,right=0pt,
    middle=0mm,% unorthodox, but boxsep has a positive value <------------ Edited 
}

\newtoggle{showans} %etoolbox
\togglefalse{showans}

\newcommand{\yesnoans}[1]{\iftoggle{showans}{#1}{\color{white} #1}}

\newenvironment{ansonoff}{%
  \iftoggle{showans}{}{\color{white}\tcbset{lowerbox=invisible}}% <------------ Edited 
  \begin{examsolv}\tcblower%
  }{\end{examsolv}%
}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{test}\label{sc:testsc}

Switcher "showans" is off, but only the side text is hidden, the body still is showed.

\begin{ansonoff}
\exampleboxedtext
that the ref with link like this \autoref{sc:testsc} cannot be hidden.
this is a new problem! the typing text also cannot be hidden.
\end{ansonoff}

\lipsum[66]

\begin{examsolv}
\lipsum[66]
\end{examsolv}

\lipsum[66]

\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[66]
\begin{ansonoff}
    \lipsum[66-70]
\end{ansonoff}
\item \lipsum[66]
\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks to Sturm. the second solution does better, it can set the text and links invisible, that is what i want. I move the overlay code to define of newenvironment, that can avoid drawing the frame when the answer is hidden.

Comment: Also thanks to Sturm for contributing the tcolorbox package!